# Test homogeneity of multivariate dispersion with regard to the Modified Raup-Crick Metric

Tags: multivariate-analysis, ecology, dispersion, diversity

Please find a citation for the modified Raup-Crick Metric below

[Modified Raup-Crick Metric (Chase et al. 2011](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1890/ES10-00117.1)

As an extremely brief review, this metric generates a dissimilarity matrix containing values "ranging from −1 to 1, indicating whether local communities are more dissimilar (approaching 1), as dissimilar (approaching 0), or less dissimilar (approaching −1), than expected by random chance." The metric is able to generate an expectation of random community assembly by explicitly accounting for variation in alpha-diversity (which can be thought of as a form of sampling bias). This involves the use of bootstrapping probability distributions for community structure via site-occupancy values of a global taxon pool.

One of the fascinating things about this metric is that it can be used to determine if differences in beta-diversity among communities are the result of differences in alpha diversity (i.e. sampling effects) alone or result via a secondary mechanism. This is determined by examining the multivariate dispersion of groups.

Groups that have a higher degree of multivariate dispersion are less deviant from the null expectation and groups which have a lesser degree of multivariate dispersion are more deviant from the null expectation. By combining this analysis with measures of the overall null deviation of a group (-.95 vs .95 for example) one can make inferences about possible ecological mechanisms generating observed diversity patterns.

My question relates to the measurement of multivariate with regard to this metric. As previously noted, values generated by the Raup-Crick metric can range from -1 to 1. When analyzing multivariate dispersion of dissimilarity metrics (such as Bray-Curtis) I typically utilize [Marti Anderson's PERMDISP2 procedure for the analysis of multivariate homogeneity of group dispersions](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1461-0248.2006.00926.x). However, this test does not accept dissimilarity matrices which contain negative values. Can anyone recommend an alternative test of group dispersion that would be suitable for this application?

Thank you greatly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page 4, final paragraph, Chase 2011 says:

> Step 5. Standardize the metric to range from1 to 1. Subtract 0.5 from
> the value from step 4, and multiply by 2.

> Step 5 represents our
> primary modification of the original Raup-Crick metric (other than
> expressing it as a dissimilarity rather than similarity), by
> re-scaling it to vary from 1 to 1.

Perhaps if you skip this step and leave the original metric (which varies from 0 to 1), it will work with the PERMDISP2 function.

Comment: That's what I ultimately wound up doing. Thank you for the input!